# The current session is not interactive

Tags: asp.net

I have developed  web page for displaying certificates using  X509Certificate2UI  class. It's working fine when it is running at local host It's displaying all certificates, I could choose the certificate, subsequently I am using certificate  for digital signing a pdf document, but when I deployed it on web server it is showing exception, The current session is not interactive. It is not showing any certificates. Any one had ever face this problem. If so please guide me how to resolve this issue. I really confused why it is behaving in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are often in "stores".  Sometimes USer Stores are tied to windows users.  Try setting "Load User Profile" in IIS app pool to make it interactive.   However this may not be enough to make it interactive the way your code is assuming.

Make sure you understand what store you are using at runtime.

I would write my code so that it did Not require an interactive session.   Store in Machine store or in files.